# Avro serialization with generic type issue

Tags: scala, generics, avro, avro4s

I need to write a function in Scala that returns an Array of byte serializated with AvroOutputStream, but in scala i can't get the class of the generic object i'm passing in input.
Here is my util class:

```
class AvroUtils {

    def createByteArray[T](obj: T): Array[Byte] = {
        val byteArrayStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream()
        val output = AvroOutputStream.binary[T](byteArrayStream)
        output.write(obj)
        output.close()
        byteArrayStream.toByteArray()
    }
}
```

As you can see if tou test this code is that AvroOutputStream can't recognize the T class so it can't generate a schema for it.
Hope you can help! thanks

PS: Already tried with TypeTag and ClassTag, nothing works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the proper implicits for `T`, namely `SchemaFor` and `ToRecord`:

```
def createByteArray[T : SchemaFor : ToRecord](obj: T): Array[Byte] = {
  val byteArrayStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream()
  val output = AvroOutputStream.binary[T](byteArrayStream)
  output.write(obj)
  output.close()
  byteArrayStream.toByteArray()
}
```

Comment: maybe ...  def createByteArray[T : SchemaFor : ToRecord](obj: T): Array[Byte] ?

Comment: i have another problem
if one of the field is AnyRef 
AvroInputStream.binary[T](byteArrayStream)

failed to compile with : Could not find implicit SchemaFor