# Avro4s generic toByteArray / fromByteArray

Tags: scala, scala-macros, scala-reflect, scala-generics, avro4s

I has a problems with generic version toByteArray / fromByteArray functions for Avro4s

I found this [Avro serialization with generic type issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48927440/avro-serialization-with-generic-type-issue)

this is works:

```
def fromByteArray[A: SchemaFor : FromRecord](bytes: Array[Byte]): Option[A] = {
    val in: ByteArrayInputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes)
    val input: AvroBinaryInputStream[A] = AvroInputStream.binary[A](in)
    val result: Option[A] = input.iterator.toSeq.headOption
    input.close()
    result
  }
```

but this is not!

```
def toByteArray[T : SchemaFor : FromRecord](obj: T): Array[Byte] = {
    val byteArrayStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream()
    val output = AvroOutputStream.binary[T](byteArrayStream)
    output.write(obj)
    output.close()
    byteArrayStream.toByteArray
  }
```

it throws compile exception:

> Error:(48, 44) could not find implicit value for evidence parameter of
>   type com.sksamuel.avro4s.ToRecord[T]
>       val output = AvroOutputStream.binaryT Error:(48, 44) not enough arguments for method binary: (implicit
>   evidence$23: com.sksamuel.avro4s.SchemaFor[T], implicit evidence$24:
>   com.sksamuel.avro4s.ToRecord[T])com.sksamuel.avro4s.AvroBinaryOutputStream[T].
>   Unspecified value parameter evidence$24.
>       val output = AvroOutputStream.binaryT

what i am doing wrong?

**upd**
stupid mistake

```
def toByteArray[T : SchemaFor : FromRecord](obj: T): Array[Byte] ...
```

must be

```
def createByteArray[T : SchemaFor : ToRecord](obj: T): Array[Byte] ...
```

:D

**on problem not solved yet**

if one of the field of class is AnyRef

```
val output = AvroOutputStream.binary[T](byteArrayStream)
```

failed to compile with : Could not find implicit SchemaFor ...

Comment: Thanks for the heads up. Updated the answer.

Comment: You cannot generate a schema for `AnyRef` because it could be one of an infinite number of subtypes.